# Falha de segmentação(imagem do nucleo gravada)

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade, fiz o código, ele está funcionando normalmente no windows. No Ubuntu ele está compilando, quando eu começo a usar a função Insere, ele dá esse erro que está no assunto.

Segue o meu código:

```
#define N 11
int tamanho = 1; //Numero de inserções

typedef struct pessoa{
int idadep;
char nomep[20];
char enderecop[20];
struct pessoa *prox;
}Pessoa;

void inicializa(Pessoa **p){
*p = NULL;
}

int iq(char Nome[]);

void insere(Pessoa **p, char nome[], int idade, char endereco[]){
Pessoa *ultimo,*aux,*penultimo;
int i = 0;
tamanho++;
// printf("inserindo %s no vetor de posicao %d\n",nome,iq(nome));

aux = (Pessoa*) malloc(sizeof(Pessoa));
ultimo = (Pessoa*) malloc(sizeof(Pessoa));
penultimo = (Pessoa*) malloc(sizeof(Pessoa));

if (*p == NULL){
//  printf("nulo\n");
strcpy(ultimo->nomep,nome);
ultimo->idadep = idade;
strcpy(ultimo->enderecop,endereco);
ultimo->prox = NULL;
*p = ultimo;

}
else{
penultimo = *p;
ultimo = *p;
while(ultimo != NULL){
if(strcmp(nome,ultimo->nomep) < 0){//nome tem que ficar antes de ultimo->nome
strcpy(aux->nomep,nome);
aux->idadep = idade;
strcpy(aux->enderecop,endereco);
aux->prox = ultimo;
if(i == 0)
*p = aux;
else{
penultimo->prox = aux;
}
break; //sai do while
}
else if(strcmp(nome, ultimo->nomep) == 0) //O nome a ser inserido já existe na lista
return;
else{ //nome tem que ficar depois de ultimo->nome
if(ultimo->prox == NULL){ //chegou ao final, então insere ele no final
strcpy(aux->nomep,nome);
aux->idadep = idade;
strcpy(aux->enderecop,endereco);
aux->prox = NULL;
ultimo->prox = aux;
break;
}
penultimo = ultimo;
ultimo = ultimo->prox;
}
i++;
}
}
}

void consulta(Pessoa **p, char nome[]){
Pessoa *aux;
aux = *p;
while(aux != NULL){
if (strcmp(aux->nomep, nome) == 0){
printf("%s\n", aux->nomep);
printf("%d\n", aux->idadep);
printf("%s\n", aux->enderecop);
}
aux = aux->prox;
}
}

void Remove(Pessoa** p, char nome[] ){
Pessoa* ant, * aux;
ant = NULL;
aux = *p;
while(aux != NULL && strcmp(aux->nomep, nome) !=0){
ant = aux;
aux = aux->prox;
}
if (aux == NULL || p == NULL){
return;
}
else if(ant == NULL && strcmp(aux->nomep, nome) ==0){ //tá no primeiro elemento
*p = aux->prox;
}
else if(aux->prox == NULL && strcmp(aux->nomep, nome) ==0){
ant->prox = NULL;
}
else{
ant->prox = aux->prox;
}
}

void print(Pessoa **p){
Pessoa *aux;
aux = *p;
while (aux != NULL){
printf("%s \n", aux->nomep);
//printf("%d \n", aux->idadep);
//printf("%s \n", aux->enderecop);
aux = aux->prox;
}
}


int ordc(char LetraNome){
int x;

if(LetraNome == ' ')
return 27;
else{
if(LetraNome >= 65 && LetraNome <= 90) //Entre A e Z
x = LetraNome - 64;
else //Entre a e z
x = LetraNome - 96;
}
return x;
}

int iq(char Nome[]){
int i, rordc = 0;

for(i = 0; i < strlen(Nome); i++){
rordc += ordc(Nome[i]);
}
return rordc%N;
}

void criaHeap(Pessoa *vet, int i, int f){
Pessoa aux = vet[i];
int j = i * 2 + 1;
while (j <= f){
if(j < f){
if(strcmp(vet[j].nomep,vet[j + 1].nomep) < 0){
j = j + 1;
}
}
if(strcmp(aux.nomep, vet[j].nomep) < 0 ){
vet[i] = vet[j];
i = j; //j é o novo pai
j = 2 * i + 1;
}else{
j = f + 1;
}
}
vet[i] = aux;
}

void heapSort(Pessoa *vet, int n){
int i;
Pessoa aux;
for(i=(n - 1)/2; i >= 0; i--){
criaHeap(vet, i, n-1);
}
for (i = n-1; i >= 1; i--){
aux = vet[0];
vet [0] = vet [i];
vet [i] = aux;
criaHeap(vet, 0, i - 1);
}
}

int salvaLista(Pessoa* v, int tamV, Pessoa** p){
Pessoa *aux;
aux = *p;
int i = tamV;
while (aux != NULL){
strcpy(v[i].nomep,aux->nomep);
v[i].idadep = aux->idadep;
strcpy(v[i].enderecop,aux->enderecop);
aux = aux->prox;
i++;
}
return i;
}

void imprimeTudo(Pessoa **p){
Pessoa* copia = (Pessoa*) malloc(sizeof(Pessoa)*tamanho);
int tam = 0, in;
for(in = 0 ; in < N; in++)
tam = salvaLista(copia,tam,&p[in]);
heapSort(copia,tam);
for(in = 0 ; in < tam; in++)
printf("%s\n", copia[in].nomep);
}

int main(){
int indice, idade, qtd, in = 0;
char metodo, nome[20], endereco[20];
Pessoa **p = (Pessoa**) malloc(sizeof(Pessoa*)*N);
for(in = 0; in < N; in++)
inicializa(&p[in]);
while(metodo != 'e'){
scanf("%c", &metodo);
switch(metodo){
case 'i':
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &qtd);
for(in = 0; in < qtd; in++){
fflush(stdin);
gets(nome);
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&idade);
fflush(stdin);
gets(endereco);
fflush(stdin);
insere(&p[iq(nome)], nome, idade, endereco);
}
break;
case 'r':
fflush(stdin);
gets(nome);
Remove(&p[iq(nome)], nome);
break;
case 'c':
fflush(stdin);
gets(nome);
consulta(&p[iq(nome)], nome);
break;
case 'l':
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &indice);
print(&p[indice]);
break;
case 'o':
fflush(stdin);
imprimeTudo(p);
break;
}

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: C ou C++, qual é a linguagem?

Comment: O trabalho deve ser em C

Comment: Onde exatamente esta dando erro? Aproveite e faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender a respeito do funcionamento e das regras do site.

Comment: Peço desculpas, eu estava editando o título quando editaram pra mim, é que eu estou sofrendo com esse erro há 6 horas no mínimo, e nem prestei atenção...
Então, o meu código compila, depois disso eu vou usar o insere, digito "i" e começo a inserir, por exemplo:
i
4
Matheus
20
rua teste
Quando dou enter no endereço, ele dá falha de segmentação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está esquecendo de inicializar um monte de variáveis locais, bem como verificar os tamanhos das entradas que você está recebendo, e isso pode gerar a falha de segmentação dependendo em que você escreve de entrada para o seu programa. Vamos seguir o chinês:

1. Você entra em `main()`. Cria as variáveis locais:

   - `indice` (sem valor),
   - `idade` (sem valor),
   - `qtd` (sem valor),
   - `in` (0),
   - `metodo` (sem valor),
   - `nome` (vetor de 20 `char`s, com lixo),
   - `endereco` (vetor de 20 `char`s, com lixo),
   - `p` (*array* de `N` ponteiros para structs `Pessoa`).
2. Reinicializa `in` com zero e usa-a para iterar sobre `p`, chamando `inicializa()` sobre cada elemento daquele vetor. `inicializa()`, por sua vez, meramente atribui a `p[in]` o valor `NULL`.
3. entra num `while` esperando que `metodo` seja igual a `'e'` — note que, como `metodo` *não foi inicializado*, existe 1 chance em 256 de que o espaço de memória de `metodo` contenha o byte `0x65`, fazendo com que o programa misteriosamente termine o seu funcionamento imediatamente.
4. Obtém-se uma informação do usuário (sem *prompt*) sobre qual a operação que se quer executar; o usuário aperta `i [enter]`, e o sistema continua.
5. O sistema faz um `switch` sobre o valor de `metodo`, e entra no ramo `case 'i':`, imediatamente descartando os valores restantes em `stdin`. Isso é ótimo para tratamento interativo, mas se o usuário resolver redirecionar `stdin` para automatizar sua digitação, aqui a entrada preparada em arquivo e redirecionada é jogada fora, e o programa chega em um impasse.
6. O sistema preenche a variável `nome` usando `gets()` (novamente sem , o que significa que, se o usuário digitar um nome com mais de 19 caracteres, o sistema entrou em *buffer overflow* e vai começar a sobrescrever as outras variáveis locais na pilha.
7. O sistema novamente descarta o resto de entrada em `stdin` usando `fflush()` e aguarda (sem *prompt*) o usuário entrar um número, cuja validade tampouco é verificada. Se o usuário não entrar um número aqui, a variável `idade` continuará contendo lixo e a execução seguirá.
8. O sistema, mais uma vez, descarta o resto de entrada e aguarda (sem *prompt*) o usuário entrar um endereço; novamente, se o usuário entrar um endereço com mais de 19 caracteres, o sistema sobrescreverá as outras variáveis locais, o *buffer* de `nome` e possivelmente até mesmo o endereço de retorno de `main()`.
9. O sistema tenta fazer a inserção de `(nome, idade, endereço)` na célula `iq(nome)` de `p`:

   1. `iq()` itera sobre os elementos de `nome`, acumulando os valores de `ordc(nome[i])` começando com 0.

      1. `ordc()`, por sua vez, retorna o valor alfabético de cada letra `A-Z` ou `a-z` maiúscula ou minúscula, ou retorna 27 para um espaço. Para caracteres acentuados como `'á'` ou `'ç'`, `ordc()` retorna o valor não-inicializado de `x`.
   2. `iq()` finalmente retorna o resultado acumulado módulo o número de casas em `p`. No caso do nome de teste `Matheus`, ele retorna 13 + 1 + 20 + 8 + 5 + 21 + 19 = 87 mod 11 = 10.
10. `insere()` começa a executar, recebendo o endereço de `p[10]`, `Matheus`, `20` e `Rua Teste` em `p`, `nome`, `idade` e `endereço`, respectivamente. As seguintes variáveis locais são criadas:

    - `ultimo`, ponteiro para Pessoa (apontando para um segmento aleatório de memória);
    - `aux`, idem;
    - `penultimo`, ibidem;
    - i, inteiro (valor 0).
11. A global `tamanho`, que foi inicializada na memória com 1, é incrementada para 2.
12. `aux`, `ultimo` e `penultimo` cada um recebe um objeto na memória alocado via `malloc()`.
13. O sistema verifica se a posição de `p` está vazia. Como está, entramos no primeiro ramo.
14. `nome` é copiado para `ultimo->nomep` usando `strcpy()`, que sobrescreverá o resto da estrutura caso `nome` tenha mais de 19 caracteres, mas neste caso concreto não.
15. `endereco` é igualmente copiado para `ultimo->enderecop` usando `strcpy()`, abrindo a possibilidade de *buffer overflow*, e `idade` também é copiada para `ultimo->idadep`. A posição de `p` passa a apontar para `ultimo` e o sistema retorna, sem desalocar `penultimo` e `aux` que foram alocados inutilmente, gerando um vazamento de memória.
16. O sistema sai de `insere()`, volta para o topo do `for`, elimina o resto da entrada e aguarda (sem *prompt*) a entrada do segundo nome. No entanto, antes disso você afirma que, no Ubuntu, o programa para com uma falha de segmentação, que quer dizer que ele está tentando escrever em memória não alocada. Isso pode ser devido a uma falha no `malloc()` de `ultimo` no Ubuntu, por exemplo, visto que você não verifica se a alocação foi bem-sucedida. Se não for, `ultimo` será `NULL` e o `strcpy()` gerará a falha de segmentação.

Em todo caso, procure corrigir esses problemas para que o seu código se torne mais robusto, e depois tente novamente. Se não funcionar, sugiro que compile com a *flag* `-g` e tente executar pelo `gdb`:

- digite `gdb meuexecutavel`, depois que vir o *prompt* digite `run[enter]` e o seu programa estará executando.
- digite os valores de entrada até o ponto que ocorrer o erro, quando o *prompt* do `gdb` voltará a aparecer. Aí você pode digitar `list` para ver a linha onde o erro ocorreu e digitar `print [variável]` para ver o valor de uma variável qualquer. Pelo menos uma delas vai estar com um valor inesperado, e a partir daí você pode determinar com mais precisão o que aconteceu.